# How to call a method in thisWorkbook from a module in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a method in thisWorkbook.

I want to call it from an other excel vba module, what's the exact syntax ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ThisWorkbook.MethodName
```

Intellisense won't show it though.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `ThisWorkbook!MethodName` ?

Comment: @mbmast `ThisWorkbook!MethodName` would be a short form of `ThisWorkbook.Item("MethodName")`, if `ThisWorkbook` had a default parametrized property (an indexer). It does not have one, and even if it did, this would retrieve the property's value, not call a method. You are probably thinking about separating the sheet name from the range address in an Excel formula, which is a completely different subject.